# When is WSO2 ELB going to support CPU-based auto scaling algorithm

Tags: wso2

WSO2 folks

I'm wondering when WSO2 ELB is going to support CPU-based auto scaling algorithm. I didn't find any roadmap for the products.

Regards,
Terry

Answer (score 2):

Implementing a load balancing algorithm which balance load based on server load is on the road map for WSO2 ELB but unable to provide an exact time frame as of now. This will be developed and released with future ELB versions.

Comment: Hold on  .. Original question is about CPU-based auto-scaling algorithm, not CPU-based load balancing algorithm. Those are two different concerns.

Answer (score 0):

We're re-architecturing WSO2 ELB in a manner that it only does load balancing requests not auto-scaling. For auto-scaling we will introduce a new component and that way we could do CPU-based auto-scaling pretty easily. Stay in touch.

Comment: Any idea when is this scaling component due to be released?  It's been a year since the last comment...